# Why are my Firefox tabs so tall on a Windows 8 tablet?

Tags: firefox, windows-8-preview

My tabs in Firefox are extremely tall. Does anyone know why this might be?

[image]

I'm using Windows 8 developer preview on a Samsung prototype tablet.

Answer (score 1):

If other title bars are also of that size, it's probably a Windws customization added in Windows 8 that has more tall tabs by default when you use a tablet. Someone needs to confirm this though.

Please note that in the near future [Firefox for Tablets](http://www.businessinsider.com/firefox-for-tablets-2011-8) will most likely release...